# What anime that has a character with green marble in his eye that gives him special abilities/superpowers

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm trying to remember the name of an anime I watched back in the mid 2000, it was possibly made in the 90s.

The premise from what I remember was post-apocalyptic world where planet Earth has been completely destroyed and now people live on other planets. There are these 7 or 8 special marbles/gems that give their user super powers/special abilities. Also these marbles/gems if collected and used together can bring back planet Earth.

There is one particular character that had white hair about ear length and used the green coloured marble/gem which was placed in his eye socket.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember any of the special powers that the gems gave their owners?

Comment: Hi thank you :)   Sorry I don't remember the abilities, but I remember the main characters were out laws and were always getting chased by the police. In one episode on some plant/colony they got help by a group of rebels that they said they were hiding underneath the police station because no one would expect that.